# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_m \otimes \mathbb{Z}_n\cong \mathbb{Z}_d$

Tags: homological-algebra, tensor-products

Show that $\mathbb{Z}_m \otimes \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_d$, for $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $d=\gcd(m,n)$.

I've looked at tensor but couldn't find a detailed solution to this problem. I would be very grateful if you could help me with this question.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the upvotes, as 1) there are countless duplicates of this question, and 2) this shows no effort in trying to solve the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}_{m} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{d}$ and that no smaller multiple of $1 \otimes 1$ is zero.

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal domain and $m(1\otimes 1) = n(1\otimes 1) = 0$, so there exist $x$ and $y$ for which

$$\gcd(m, n) = d = xm + yn.$$

This implies $d(1 \otimes 1) = (xm + yn)(1\otimes 1) = x(m(1\otimes 1)) + y(n(1\otimes 1)) = 0,$ which means that the tensor product $\mathbb{Z}_{m} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Define a mapping $f : \mathbb{Z}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ so that $f(a, b) = ab$. Also, let $g$ be the induced $R$-linear mapping. Observe that $g$ maps $1 \otimes 1$ to $1$. The equality $c(1 \otimes 1) = 0$ means that $d$ divides $c$, and the result follows.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: Ok but why downvote the answer? Literally makes 0 sense @Shaun.

Comment: I'm just enforcing quality standards, @AryanDugar. Answers to PSQs and duplicates are discouraged.

Comment: If you have a problem, @AryanDugar, then you can take it up on the meta site.

Comment: Is the meta site suggesting you to downvote such answers? I doubt it.